# A rota do slim não está pegando o callable

Tags: php, rotas, slim

Ele pega o methods e patterns, mas parece que ele está ingorando o callable.

```
$group->group('/figure', function (\Slim\Routing\RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
                $group->map(['GET'], '/view/{hash_figure}', ['\App\Controller\FigureController', 'get'])->setName('figure.get');
                $group->map(['GET'], '/register/{hash_figure}', ['\App\Controller\FigureController', 'form'])->setName('figure.form');
                $group->map(['POST'], '/register', ['\App\Controller\FigureController', 'post'])->setName('figure.post');
                $group->map(['POST'], '/update/{hash_figure}', ['\App\Controller\FigureController', 'put'])->setName('figure.put');
                $group->map(['POST'], '/view/{hash_figure}', ['\App\Controller\FigureController', 'delete'])->setName('figure.delete');
            });
```

esse é o html:

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{{ url_for('figure.delete', {'hash_figure' : figure.hash})}}" role="button">Deletar</a>`

qualquer rota que eu der pra ele ir ele vai, mas pra chamar a função do Controller não está funcionando e isso **é só no último que não está funcionando** o resto de cima está...
alguém sabe dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Poderia informar qual o erro que está sendo retornado?

Comment: não tem erro, ele simplesmente vai pra uma pag e não executa a função de delete

Comment: Tenta compartilhar o código do controller também. Temos muito poucas informações para te ajudar.

Comment: Você definiu sua rota com o método  POST, porém quando você clica no link (`<a>`), você acessa a página com o método GET.